# I'm using to use google maps and need to get names like ocean, sea etc from location in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am unable to get name of oceans from location but able to get address of other place using [this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=13.025867,64.096760&result_type=natural_feature&key=my_key) , which is lat-lng of Arabian sea.

Means not getting name of natural places like ocean, sea etc. Please help me to find this out?

Comment: You shouldn't post you `KEY` on forums...

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `latlong(0,0)` pass real latlong to get result.

Comment: I'm using real latlong  even than I'm stuck

Comment: you have entered wrong key . please enter right key to solve your problem

Comment: I have used server key that created from google console

Comment: do not use server key use API key

Comment: I have created a API key
First I opened google developer console-> my project-> credentials-> click on create credentials-> Select API key-> server key

Answer (score 0):

Your API Key is invalid.

To create new API Key:
Go to "Google Developer Console" --> "Project" --> "Credentials" --> "Create Credentials" --> "API Key" --> "Android Key" --> Give it a Name & Add SHA Key --> Click "Create" --> Go to "Library" --> Click "Google Maps Geocoding API" --> Click "enable"

On the other hand, your latitude and longitude seems incorrect. I tried to check your latitude and longitude with my API key and I am getting zero results with your provided lat and longs.

Comment: I am not getting the address of oceans, sea etc and  getting address of other places. This mean my api is valid. please let me know how to get name of oceans from latlng